# setOnclickListener for ListView

Tags: android

How to set onClickListener on a `ListView`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnQueryTextListener,OnItemClickListener {

    SQLDatabaseSource db;
    List<ThuatNgu> list;
    ListView lvHienThi;
    CustomListView adapter;
    public static String chuoiTimKiemKiem = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lvHienThi = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvHienThi);

        list = new ArrayList<ThuatNgu>();
        db = new SQLDatabaseSource(this);
        list = db.DanhSach();

        setAdapterListView(list);

    }

    private void setAdapterListView(List<ThuatNgu> list){
         adapter = new CustomListView(this, R.layout.custom_layout_listview, list);
         lvHienThi.setAdapter(adapter);
         ***`lvHienThi.setOnClickListener(this);`***


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String chuoi) {
        list = db.TimKiem(chuoi);
        setAdapterListView(list);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        chuoiTimKiemKiem = chuoi;
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
        Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this,"Tot",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }


}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Whats the problem??? If any crash please post the logcat error trace.

Comment: Did my answer work for you??

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code I see this is the problem although your question doesn't say anything. I hope this is what you want.

Use this

```
 lvHienThi.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```